# Lost six outlets voltage intermittent and breaker's not tripping

Tags: electrical

Any ideas on how I can go about testing this it's reading open hot and With  with a multimeter the voltage is intermittent. Pops up to 120 counts down to about 60 volts then 120

[image]

Comment: All on one breaker or multiple breakers?

Comment: Do you get similar fluctuating readings on other outlets in the house, or worse yet, *higher* readings than 120 on 120V outlets?

Comment: What does the "is white" label in the picture mean? What, specifically, does this box full of switches have to do with "Lost six outlets" in the title question? What is "reading open hot"? In what way does what thing "count down to about 60 volts"? Needs a _lot_ of additional details. Remember, we can't read your mind and in order to give you a good, safe answer, we need all the details that are in your head but that you didn't provide.

Comment: Based on the poor workmanship of who ever wired that switch I'd lean towards the advice from @crip659. If it was me I would check every connection in that circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Intermittent is usually a broken or loose wire.

A broken wire inside of insulation can make connection sometimes and is hard to find, but usually low on list of possibilities.

A loose connection can sometimes be caused by cheap push in connections found on outlets.  Best fix is to change to the screws.

Turn off breaker/s and check for power before pulling outlets and checking.